# The uniform integrability of exponential of Poisson process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\left\{N_t,\mathcal{F}_t\right\}_{t\ge0}$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda>0$. Define
$$X_t=\exp{\left[N_t-\lambda t(e-1)\right]}$$
I can show that $\{X_t,\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\ge0}$ is a martingale. But I don't know whether this martingale is uniformly integrable which is equivalent to that it converges in $L^1$ as $t\to\infty$.

Can anyone give some hints or references?

Comment: What do you think it might converge to? (It has jumps by a factor of $e$).